# SSL connection problems in JRE1.7

Tags: java, ssl

I have two Java programs (client and server) which worked perfect for years until I upgraded to java 1.7. They are connected through SSL sockets.

In JRE 1.7 the connections hangs-up, i.e. the read function does not return anything at some point (works for a number of bytes then blocks even the bytes are coming). What is weird is if I run the code from the NetBeans IDE it works perfect, I have this problem only when I run from command line or double click the .jar file. It also works fine with JRE 1.6 or earlier.

If I disable SSL it seems to work.

Is there a known problem with SSL in JRE 1.7 or did anybody see similar issues.

Please, advise. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found and reported a similar problem with JDK 1.7 on Linux and Mac OS (but not on Windows), when using Diffie-Hellman based ciphers. Disabling those ciphers may be a workaround. See https://forums.oracle.com/message/11001587?tstart=0